# Save and Load boolean status

Tags: android, button, save, boolean, sharedpreferences

How can I save the isEnabled() status (Boolean) of a Button and load it again after closing the application?
I tried SharedPreferences and InternalStorage but I don't really know/understand how to use it.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation from Android http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref The example shows exactly how to use boolean in shared preferences. Maybe the following is a bit unclear boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false); but the second parameter is a default value in case it is not set.

Comment: The other unclear thing is what means setSilent or where does it come from?

Comment: setSilent() is just a method in the class. But the method is not displayed in the example. But it gives an indication that you set the boolean in the example to the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
              "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //To read preferences:

        boolean isEna = prefs.getBoolean("key", false); 

        //To edit and save preferences
        boolean isEnable =  true;
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("key",isEnable).commit();
```